# Write a SQL query showing total of distinct results of field 'status' filtered per month and year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a basic knowledge in SQL but I need some help in a more complex queries.

I want to get the total count of every distinct "status" which are: 'Active'  'Awaiting User Info' | 'Closed' | 'New' | 'Resolved'

Here's the columns/result that I wanted to show:
Month when the ticket was opened filtered by year=2015, and the total count of each status

['Month' | 'Active' | 'Awaiting User Info' | 'Closed' | 'New' | 'Resolved']

I wanted the columns to be fixed even if the result is 0.

Here's my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Incidents](
[Number] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DateOpened] [datetime] NULL,
[Severity] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Priority] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Status] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select month(DateOpened),
       sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) as [Active],
       sum(case when status = 'Awaiting User Info' then 1 else 0 end) as [Awaiting User Info],
       sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as [Closed],
       sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end) as [New],
       sum(case when status = 'Resolved' then 1 else 0 end) as [Resolved]
from incidents
where year(DateOpened) = 2015
group by month(DateOpened)
```

If you want all months even if there are no records for a specific one then you can left join the table against a unioned list of month names

Answer (score 0):

You should try using nested `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`. `COUNT` will ensure you to catch also the 0 values Pay attention to fields and tables aliases:

```
    SELECT X.M, A.Act as Active, 
           AUI.Await as Awaiting_User_Info, 
           C.Clo as Closed, N.Ne as New R.Res as Resolved 
    FROM   (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M
            FROM Incidents
            GROUP BY MONTH(DateOpened) ) X
    LEFT JOIN
           (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M, 
                   COUNT(*) AS Act 
            FROM Incidents 
            WHERE Status = 'Active' 
            GROUP BY M) A
    ON X.M = A.M LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M, 
                   COUNT(*) AS Await 
            FROM Incidents 
            WHERE Status = 'Awaiting User Info' 
            GROUP BY MONTH) AUI
    ON X.M = AUI.M LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M, 
            COUNT(*) AS Clo 
            FROM Incidents 
            WHERE Status = 'Closed' GROUP BY MONTH) C
    ON X.M = C.M  LEFT JOIN 
           (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M, 
                   COUNT(*) AS Ne 
            FROM Incidents 
            WHERE Status = 'New' 
            GROUP BY MONTH) N
    ON X.M = N.M LEFT JOIN  
           (SELECT MONTH(DateOpened) as M, 
                   COUNT(*) AS Res 
            FROM Incidents 
            WHERE Status = 'Resolved' 
            GROUP BY MONTH) N
    ON X.M = R.M
```

Comment: If you `inner join` on the subqueries you get the only the months they all are present

Comment: @juergend I've edited my reply. Now all months are returned with a new subquery without conditions left joined to the others.

Answer (score 0):

i think, it will help you!

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
      month([DateOpened]) as [month], [Status],
        COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM [Incidents]
    group by month([DateOpened]) , [Status]
) as s
PIVOT
(
    SUM(cnt)
    FOR [Status] IN ( Active , [Awaiting User Info] , [Closed] , [New] , [Resolved])
)AS pivotname
```